# Do you get index error with this function?

Tags: python-3.x, function, indexing

I created this function as part of a task manager project I did for a bootcamp. The function opens a text file with task data written on it and prints a short summary of the info in a relatively presentable way.

Each task is stored on a line within the txt file as shown below:

```
employee, task title, task description, date of task creation, due date, yes/no (depending if task complete)
```

The guy who reviewed my project came back to me and said there is an indexing error with this function. I've run this program dozens of times to try and see how he is getting this error message but it seems to be working just fine. What am I missing?

```
def view_all():
    with open ("tasks-Copy1.txt", "r") as tasks:
        print ("\nTASKLIST")
        for line in tasks:
        print ("\nTask Title: {}".format(line.split(",")[1]))
        print ("Task Description: {}".format(line.split(",")[2]))
        print ("due date:{}".format(line.split(",")[4]))
        print ("Responsible user: {}".format(line.split(",")[0]))
        print ("")
        print ("")
```

This is how the heading and first task (written on the top line) are displayed when I run the program:

```
TASKLIST

Task Title:  test
Task Description:  test to see if code works
due date: 01/01/2022
Responsible user: jay
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, when you read data from an external source (or receive data as a parameter to your function),  you should not take for granted that the format is correct. There might be some data missing on some line (for whatever reason).
So the good practice is to always validate that the info is present before accessing it directly with an index.

In your case, to make sure you never get an index error, you should do something like that:

```py
def view_all():
    with open ("tasks-Copy1.txt", "r") as tasks:
        print ("\nTASKLIST")
        for line in tasks:
            values = line.split(",")
            if len(values) >= 5:
                print ("\nTask Title: {}".format(values[1]))
                print ("Task Description: {}".format(values[2]))
                print ("due date:{}".format(values[4]))
                print ("Responsible user: {}".format(values[0]))
                print ("")
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an error when I look at it overall, but perhaps they have inadvertently put the wrong input? Just make sure that they have used it properly.